# I just deleted "/bin". What's the best way to recover?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I just ran (not on purpose!) `rm -rf /bin`.

I've booted down the computer and am using Finnix to try to recover from it. I have succeeded in mounting the drive, and confirmed that, yes, the entire `/bin` folder is deleted.

Is it possible to recover from this without reinstalling the OS?

I'm thinking that I could setup a VM with the same OS and architecture (Ubuntu Server 11.10 alpha release, x86) and install all the packages I had installed on the server, then just copy the `/bin` folder.

Will this work? Am I better off just starting over?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In general, I'd lean towards a reinstall (from the backups you are absolutely supposed to have).  But I'm feeling hackish, so here's another way (assuming that your system is mounted under `/target`):

1. Get a list of all the installed packages that have files in `/bin`:

   ```
   grep ^/bin/ /target/var/lib/dpkg/info/*.list | sed 's%^.*/\([^/\.]*\).list%\1%' >/tmp/pkglist
   ```

   (On my Debian Squeeze system that's a total of 34 packages, pretty much all of which are core)
2. Download each of those packages (I couldn't be bothered to script this bit, so just hit up packages.ubuntu.com and download them into somewhere under `/target`).  If you're lucky some of the packages might still be floating around in `/target/var/cache/apt/archives`.
3. For each package, run `/target/usr/bin/dpkg -x <package> /target`.  I'm fairly certain `dpkg` is all self-contained these days, and shouldn't call out to anything in `/bin` itself.

Once you've got the system back on it's feet, you should make sure and run an `apt-get --reinstall install <all the packages from step 1>`, because (since you're running a pre-release, which Sysadmin Cat says is a no-no on production systems) the versions of the packages you just extracted are likely to be different from those that were on the system before, and you'll want to make sure the system knows exactly what's what.

Comment: Nice answer, but am I missing something? Wouldn't `dpkg-query -S /bin` do the same than your `grep .. | sed` stanza? If the list needs to be cleaned up to list one package name per line, then `dpkg-query -S /bin | sed 's/\,\ /\n/g'` works (though having extra :/bin on the last line).

Comment: Yes, it would -- I was trying to minimise the amount of stuff run in the target system in case whatever was run needed something in `/bin`, and I didn't want to rely on anything Debian-specific in the rescue system to make it as general as possible for future finders.

Comment: It seems like this is a list of only the essential system utilities—aren't there also other packages which have files in `/bin`? Should I reinstall every package on my system, or just the ones generated as the result of the list? (Also: thanks, I love you!)

Comment: Typically, only essential packages will have files in `/bin` -- most packages should put all their data under `/usr`.  On my system, only a couple of non-essential packages (eg. `zsh`) are in the "has stuff in `/bin`" list.  Upvotes are a great way to show love, by the way...

Comment: I followed your instructions and they worked perfectly—my server is back up and running. Thanks a ton for the help!

Answer (score 5):

While your strategy may work (there are good chances for it, more if once you copy back the bin directory, you do an apt-get reinstall of all the packages in you system), it can yield problems in the future because you may get an unstable server.

If that would have happened to me, I would reinstall and restore from the daily backup. You have a daily backup - a disaster recovery plan - don't you?

In case you didn't have a disaster recovery plan, I would suggest to backup all the config files and the data you want to preserve and go ahead with a reinstall. That way you'll be sure that you'll end with a stable server again.

Comment: guessing since he posted here how to recover the /bin folder he doesn't have a backup.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no daily backup. The bash script I was writing at the time was, ironically, a daily backup script. Looks like I'll be reinstalling—thanks for the advice.

Comment: No need to reinstall; see my answer.

Comment: File system snapshots are extremely useful for recovering from things like this. Unfortunately ext2/3/4 file systems do not implement them and doing it with LVM has a big performance penalty. If I accidentally delete /bin on my FreeBSD box, I just mount an earlier snapshot and copy the files back to the live version of the file system. OS X supposedly also has this (it is called "time machine" there).

Answer (score 3):

I would try creating a VM then copying the contents of `/bin` to your damaged machine. That should get you up and running. Then run

```
dpkg --get-selections  | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -l1 aptitude reinstall
```

which should reinstall all the packages that were on your system.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way, if you have access to the machine, is to mount the filesystem, take a backup of all your data (just as a precaution).

Then you can re-install ubuntu like a normal install; in principle all your data (home dir, etc and var) should still be there.

There is a way to reinstall all packages so that /bin is repopulated, but that's fairly complicated.

Answer (score 0):

The files are gone. While you can attempt to "undelete" files - I wouldn't recommend it.

Note: I do not run Ubuntu (and haven't used Debian distros for a while). However I have done various distros recoveries in the past all following similar scenario.

Your best course of action:

- boot from liveCD
- using liveCD mount your system somplace (say, `/mnt/mint`)
- using dpkg query *all* installed packages:

```
# dpkg --admindir=/mnt/mint/var/lib/dpkg -l
```

- install all those packages into your /mnt/mint destination using apt-get using:

```
# apt-get -o RootDir=/mnt/mint ....
```

- (alternative #1) You may have to deboostrap `/mnt/mint` - not sure
- (alternative #2) You may copy `/bin` contents of liveCD over to `/mnt/mint/bin` but I do not know whether liveCD for mint uses busybox which may complicate matters - alternative #1 in that case seems safer.

generally this should return your files by "brute-reinstall" of everything you have. You can do bit more "clever" tricks and query for all packages that dropped binaries in /bin